# trigonometric equation using compound angle formulas

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to evaluate these 2 calculations using a compound angle formulae and not a calculator?
Sin(105°)
Cos( - 30°)

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem, note that $105^\circ = 90^\circ + 15^\circ$ and $15^\circ$ is half of $30^\circ$. So use addition and half-angle formulas.

For the second, look at the unit circle. You should see that $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, use double angle trig identity, $\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$ or $\cos\theta=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos2\theta}{2}}$ $$\sin 105^\circ=\sin(90^\circ+15^\circ)=\cos15^\circ=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos30^\circ}{2}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{2}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt3+1)^2}{8}}$$
since, $\sin 105^\circ>0 $, hence
$$\sin 105^\circ=\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{2\sqrt 2}$$ & one should get
$$\cos(-30^\circ)=\cos30^\circ=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could try $\sin(105^\circ) = \sin(60^\circ + 45^\circ)$.
If you know the sines and cosines of the angles $60^\circ$ and $45^\circ$,
the answer follows relatively directly from the formula for
the sine of a sum of angles.

As already observed, $\cos(-30^\circ) = \cos(30^\circ)$, whose value you
presumably already know.